# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 34467037488 bytes) in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, mydbr

When I load the myDBR URL through IFRAME. I getting the the following error.

**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 34467037488 bytes) in Unknown on line 0**

I have set php.ini memory_limit 1256M ans also I tried .htaccess file php_value memory_limit -1. But i did get any improvement please help me.

Comment: When PHP is trying to grab 34,467,037,488 (yes, that's 34 Gigabytes) of memory, you have a serious problem... don't try to let PHP take that much memory, figure out why it's trying to do so

Comment: And if you call this URL directly in Browser, you get not? Your problem is another.

Comment: @MarkBaker What can I do for this problem slove? Please advise me

Comment: There a 2 common reasons for this: 1. Infinity Loop or 2. reading very big Data into Memory instead of Streaming

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Yes, some times I getting that issue

Comment: @Christian - when PHP is trying to grab 34GB In one go, it's unlikely to be an infinite loop.... that would normally just grab small chunks of memory each iteration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to allocate 34GB of data.

Obviously, your memory limit of 1256Mb won't be enough.

You either need to :

- Reconsider how much ram your application need (recommended)
- Increase the memory limit to 34GB (not recommended).

Comment: In my server have 16GB ram. Is it enough or How much I need to increasing?

Comment: Obviously, my comment has **ironical**. You need to fix up your script, it shouldn't take more than a few MB of memory.

Comment: 16GB is not enough. What is your script doing, cracking the genome code? Hacking the gibson? Predicting global warming?